OneHotEncoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sparse'
getting an error while fitting with lazypredict
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
clf = LazyClassifier(verbose=0,ignore_warnings=True, custom_metric=None)
models, predictions = clf.fit(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)

TypeError: OneHotEncoder.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sparse'

Based on this GitHub issue, the problem is the upgrade of scikit-learn library. The solution is to either:

use scikit-learn<1.4

or edit the library file itself \envs\environment_name\Lib\site-packages\lazypredict\Supervised.py and change sparse=False on line 98 to sparse_output=False.
